# Robolectric does not know \p{LATIN} char property name

Tags: android, regex, robolectric

I have a regex

```
final public static Pattern ONLY_LATIN_LETTERS = Pattern.compile("[\\p{LATIN}\\p{S}\\p{P} ]*");
```

that works fine on an Android device.
When I run tests with Robolectric I get an exception when the pattern is created because LATIN is not recognized as character property name. If I use:

```
final public static Pattern ONLY_LATIN_LETTERS = Pattern.compile("[\\p{IsLatin}\\p{S}\\p{P} ]*");
```

it works with Robolectric but it throws an exception on the device.

Does this mean that Robolectric is not reliable to test the behaviour on the device?

I'm using:

```
testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"
testCompile "org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0"
testCompile "org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.0"
compile 'junit:junit:4.8.2'
```

Comment: I would create a ticket on the Robolectric GitHub. There are several issues related fact that Java on Android is not same as desktop Java

Comment: Done. Thank you. I wonder if Robilectric is still a valuable option...https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robolectric/b5ybgkn7w-g

Comment: If you post it as an answer I'll flag it as right as soon as I get a feedback from Robolectric

Comment: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now my solution was to run an Android Connected test with the AndroidJunit4 runner.
In this case you run the app on the real device and you see the char property name available there.